# Python numpy.random.choice: ValueError: Fewer non-zero entries in p than size

Tags: python, numpy

I wanna randomly select sample points based on the probability distribution specified by `prob` for a given row. However, I get the error `ValueError: Fewer non-zero entries in p than size` when I call `np.random.choice`. What is even meant by `size`? I also took a look at the [implementation](https://github.com/frsong/pyrl/blob/master/pyrl/theanotools.py) but I don't get it. Thanks for any help!!

```
import numpy as np

# prob is a numpy array of shape (14, 6890)
all_zero = np.where(prob.max(1) < 1e-6)[0] # find indices of rows where all values are smaller
prob[all_zero] = 1 / prob.shape[1] # fill those rows uniformly
prob /= prob.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
# ... somewhere later inside a method
for j in range(14):
    sample = np.random.choice(6890, 4, replace=False, p=prob[j]) # error occurs here
```

Comment: There are way more `numpy` than `torch` users. If you can reproduce that error just using `numpy` you would be reaching more people

Comment: Okay, I edited that part out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with your use of `np.random.choice` you ask to pick *4* entries without reusing values (`replace=False`) in an array of 6890 entries **with less than 4 non-null values**, for instance:

```py
>>> np.random.choice(5, 1, replace=False, p=[0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.4])
array([4])

>>> np.random.choice(5, 4, replace=False, p=[0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.4])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    np.random.choice(5, 4, replace=False, p=[0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.4])
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 826, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.choice
ValueError: Fewer non-zero entries in p than size

>>> np.random.choice(5, 4, replace=True, p=[0, 0, 0, 0.6, 0.4])
array([3, 3, 4, 3])
```

So the resolution depends on your need, you either ensure to have more non-null values, or you enable the replacement in the random choice.

As reference, the documentation of numpy.random.choice:

- https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html